# Declarative SQL Schema Migrator

Tags: mysql, sql, database-migration

All of the SQL database schema migration tools I can find ask you to define your schema as a discrete set of migration steps, which effectively amount to sequences of `CREATE/ALTER/DROP` statements.

I'm looking for a tool that enables me to describe my schema declaratively rather than procedurally, ie. as a single set of `CREATE TABLE` statements or in some other format, by which the migrator will inspect the live database (eg. using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables) and make any changes required to have it match the schema I've described.

Does such a tool exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the redgate tools, they have a compare tool and also an extension to generate deployment scripts to be used with Flyway:

"MySQL Compare":

https://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-compare/

FlySQL:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/flysql/

ed